# How to check in SQL Job step whether SSIS package exists on the server or not?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

I have a requirements to execute SSIS Package only if it is exists on the server where I am deploying all our SSIS packages.

Is there any way by which I can first check whether SSIS package exists on location from where SQL Job step is going to execute it and then execution of SQL Job step gets start?

I am deploying my package to Integration Services Catalogs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help : `select * from msdb.dbo.sysssispackages`

Comment: I have edited the question as I want to look into Integration Services Catalogs where I am deploying my packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I was able to answer the question myself.

For Integration Services Catalogs we have a separate database for SSIS Packages called **SSISDB** inside which we have a table named packages into which we can check whether the **package** exists on servers inside Integration Services Catalogs or not by below query.

```
SELECT * FROM internal.packages WHERE name LIKE 'YourPackageName.dtsx'
```

Hope this can help someone in future.